# Trying to get the value of a tag in an xml string java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have an xml string stored in a StringBuilder.
My xml looks like this

[couldn't write it in code so here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzHK1.png)

inside the report tag, it looks like
[what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPL4E.png)

I would like to get access to any tag value I want in the record tag, what I have is :

```
StringBuilder informationString = new StringBuilder();
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());

            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                informationString.append(scanner.nextLine());
            }
            //Close the scanner
            scanner.close();

            System.out.println(informationString);

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(String.valueOf(informationString))));
            Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();
```

But I do not know what to do with this and am very lost
Thanks by advance for helping

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use the below routine

```
Element documentElement=....
NodeList elmList=documentElement.getElementsByTagName("elementName");
Element e=(Element)elmList.itm(x);//putting it in a loop would do
```

You could keep using the above to get elements recursively.

Though a better approach would be to use XPath ([Saxon](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/xpath-api/) has a decent XPath implementaton, though there are many more libraries to choose from)